# TCP client server using epoll (EPOLLOUT | EPOLLET), EPOLLOUT event triggered just one time?

Tags: c

epoll TCP with EPOLLOUT | EPOLLET gets event for one time and goes to time out even if I send data after getting the first event.

While in UDP epoll keeps getting EPOLLOUT events after sending new data.

Can you explain this issue?

Comment: Care to show some code? Perhaps a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EPOLLET is edge-triggered mode, which means it will only notify you of state transitions.  In this case it will notify  you when the file descriptor goes from *not* being writable to being writable.  And the only way to make it not writable is to fill the outgoing buffer.  So you need to just keep sending until you get EAGAIN, then you'll wait for a notification.